# NGINX post_action to UNIX DOMAIN SOCKET

Tags: sockets, unix, nginx, request, unix-socket

I am trying to send(copy) all the nginx traffic to Unix Socket.

Here is the related code from my nginx.conf

```
upstream unixsocket { server unix:/var/www/tmp2.sock; }

post_action /sendLogging
location /sendLogging 
{
proxy_pass http://unixsocket;
}
```

should i start a server in this socket ?

```
socket -sl /var/www/tmp2.sock
```

If i do this, i cant see any requests coming to the socket.

Moreover because of the config, my nginx is taking huge CPU 50-90% Just while testing with ONE request.

--

**EDIT:**

My mistake, the sock file was not writable by NGINX worker process. Gave appropriate permissions.

The reason for  high CPU usage was because of the POST_ACTION tag  there was an internal redirect.

If anyone else faces INTERNAL REDIRECT issue with POST_ACTION i solved by returning 444 from the location. this works in my case.

Thanks.